# How can i make a paragraph when writing a long text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, widget

How can i make paragraphs in flutter in a text widget?
It is all just one long text and it looks stupid

What I want:
Hello,

how are you?

What it is:

Hello, how are you?

Answer (score 4):

Use `\n` for paragraphs, like this: `Text('Hello,\n\nhow are you?')`

Comment: ohh thats so easy, why dont i find something that simple on google? thx

Comment: Glad I could help! Please consider accepting my answer to get me some reputation ;) I‘m still quite new here...

Comment: There should be check mark next to the two arrows which you can select, like it‘s shown in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

another approach, use RichText:

```
RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello,',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: 'how are you?',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Bad thing about `RichText` and `TextSpan` is that you still need to format & layout your lines. By default, they are inline elements...